# How can I capture text from my terminal without redirecting it to a text file?

Tags: command-line, capture

Basically, what I would like to do is, instead of just redirecting the out from my terminal command to a file, I would like to have the information also show in the terminal session.

If I use **~$ command > output.log**  I am no longer able to see the command process in the terminal window and therefore I do not know when the command has finished processing without looking at the output.log file. The commands I run take a few minutes to process and produce quite a bit of output. (hence me wanting to capture that output)  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to your question is `tee`. Just use `| tee [output file]` instead of `> [output file]`

Thus, `sudo apt-get update > out.log`
becomes
`sudo apt-get update | tee out.log`.

For more information: [LinuxQuestion.org: BASH: How to Redirect Output to File, AND Still Have it on Screen](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/bash-how-to-redirect-output-to-file-and-still-have-it-on-screen-412611/), [Linux by Examples: How to redirect output to a file as well as display it out](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/349/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-as-well-as-display-it-out/).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `tee`.

Example: `$ls 2>&1 | tee text.txt`

This will print the output of the command into the log file as well in the Terminal.

Answer (score 3):

`command |tee output.log` both prints, and captures.