# How can I capture text from a specific terminal and redirect it to a log file while simultaneously working?

Tags: bash, redirect

I viewed [**this question**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140782/how-can-i-capture-text-from-my-terminal-without-redirecting-it-to-a-text-file) to redirect text to file while displaying the output. My question is how can I redirect it while working **AND** without constant `| tee` command.

My plan is to use [**this question**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210182/how-to-check-which-terminal-emulator-is-being-currently-used) to identify terminal (Gnome or Guake) and record only Gnome for my Linux commands testing. So I need constant and immediate redirecting of commands and their outputs (with errors) to a file (say cmdlog.log).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script command can do this, it starts a session and all output is by default captured into a file called typescript.  Alternatively, one can specify the filename to contain the captured session, e.g.

```
script capture.txt
```

..then run your commands and finally type "exit" to exit the session.

To ensure you don't get any control characters, use:

```
TERM=dump
script capture.txt
```

and when you exit, use:

```
col -b < capture.txt > cleaned-capture.txt
```

Comment: That works but how do I tell it to not to use colour while recording as it gives unknown characters while using gedit.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: OK. Now there are no unknown characters. Still need to remove colour tags though. Maybe I'll do it manually using `tr` command.