# How to get and copy a too long output completely in terminal?

Tags: 12.10, command-line, output

In terminal a command has a too long output. But when I scroll back I see it is truncated and only the last part is shown. In Gnome-Terminal and Konsole I have this problem. In xterm there's not such problem but I cannot copy the output in xterm.

How can I get the complete output?

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): [How can I capture text from a specific terminal and redirect it to a log file while simultaneously working?](http://askubuntu.com/q/216322/22949)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know in the xfce4-terminal there is a option to increase the number of lines shown:

[image]

For ubuntu `Terminal`
[image]

Aside from that there is what @Zelda64fan said.

Comment: +1 Pipe and `tee` are not optimal as dont work on few cases like take in a `HROOT 3NVIORTNM3NT`

Answer (score 11):

You could send the output to a file: `command > file.txt` (where `command` is the command you want to run and `file.txt` is the file you want to save it to) and then view it with `gedit file.txt`.

Answer (score 8):

Use xclip

```
cat long.output | xclip -sel clip
```

If not installed you can do

```
sudo apt-get install xclip
```

Comment: This one is my personal favorite for GUI terminals.  With TTY it won't  work,  unfortunately,  only redirection to a file will help there

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need the entire output, you could pipe it through less: `command | less`. This would also save the bother of having to delete the file once you've reviewed the output.

Comment: `less` output is pretty hard to copy.

Answer (score 2):

In xterm, autocopy on select should be the default. Try triple-clicking then use a middle mouse button (or emulated third button) to paste.

The same should work with other terminals, but you need to manually copy and paste.

There a many, many ways to do this.   I like using `script` in some cases.
Type 'script' from a command line to start it before you launch a command from the command line, then hit Ctrl-D to stop.  If you don't specify a capture filename, 'typescript' is the default.  Everything printed to the screen should be captured in the file.

Answer (score 2):

### Save console output into a file:

1. **`tee`** command

**tee** command - read from standard input and write to standard output and files.

It automatically creates file and save, all the output of cmd `ps -ax` into a file named as `processes_info` in the same folder from where the cmd has run.

```
user@admin:~$ ps -ax | tee processes_info
```

2. **`script`** command

**script** command - make typescript of terminal session.

```
user@admin:~$ script my_console_output.txt
```

This creates a file named as `my_console_output.txt` and will open a subshell and records all information through this session.
After this, script get started and whatever the console output, it will get stored in the file `my_console_output.txt`; unless and until the script ends when the forked shell exits. (e.g., when the user types `exit` or when <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> is typed.)

```
user@admin:~$ script -c "ps ax" processes_info.txt
```

- it starts the script;
- creates the file `processes_info.txt`;
- stores the console output into the file;
- end (close) the script.

  Other example:

  ```
   script -c 'echo "Hello, World!"' hello.txt
  ```

Comment: `script -c "rails runner -e development lib/scripts/my_script.rb" report.txt` helped me to capture a Rails runner script's very-very long output easily to a file. I tried using redirecting to a file but it got written only at the end of script. That didn't helped me because I had few interactive commands in my script. Then I used just `script` on my and then ran the `rails runner` in script session but it didn't wrote everything. Then I found this `script -c "runner command here" output_file` and it saved all the output as was desired. This was on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS